# Adb push does not work

Tags: adb, file-transfer

When I run the command

```
adb push file.txt /flash/Data
```

it writes this error message

```
failed to copy 'file.txt' to '/flash/Data': Read-only file system
```

I tried to solve it according to this page
http://android-tricks.blogspot.com/2009/01/mount-filesystem-read-write.html but with no success.

Could you navigate me and solve the problem? thank you

Comment: What device are you using?  I'm not familiar with the `/flash` folder.

Comment: my device is Archos 7. In OI File Manager I can see the flash folder. But folder is not important, I can copy it to another folder (but I don't have SD card)

Comment: OK.  As Bryan asked in his answer, what are you trying to accomplish?  Just store files?

Comment: I have problem with copying files (I asked another question about it), so I tried to solve it with adb push.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to have root access to mount the drive as that article is describing (calling su == becoming root).

What are you trying to accomplish? Can you push the file to the sdcard instead (if your device has one)?

Comment: I have problem with copying files (I asked another question about it), so I tried to solve it with adb push.

Answer (score 1):

You normally have to be [rooted](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-phone) to change how the filesystem is mounted.

Comment: I'd like to preserve warranty.

Comment: Then you should use an SD card or something to put files on, you can't write indescriminately to the system or data partitions without root.

Comment: We can use interntal flash.

Answer (score 1):

You can attempt writing to `/data/local/tmp/` as it is writable even by normal users.